# Django, configuração formato de data 'd/m/Y'

Tags: django

Não estou conseguindo alterar a configuração do Django para que o formato da data fique como 'd/m/Y'.  Na validação do formulário, caso informe 22/12/1980, o formulário fica  inválido.  Informando 12/22/1980 o campo data fica válido e consigo gravar o registro.

Já tentei alterar as seguintes configurações:

settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'
USE_L10N = False
```

Na classe, o atributo está definido como:

```
data_nascimento = models.DateField(null=False)
```

Existe mais alguma configuração para que eu possa alterar o formato de data de 'm/d/Y' para 'd/m/Y'?

Comment: Já tentou utilizar a configuração `DATE_FORMAT`?

Comment: Ainda não, onde devo informar o DATE_FORMAT, no settings.py?  Ficaria DATE_FORMAT = 'd/m/Y'?

Comment: @Anderson Incluí no settings.py, mas continuo com erro na validação "data_nascimento
Informe uma data válida.".  Qual seria o local correto para informar o DATE_FORMAT?  Obrigado.

Comment: Sim, é no `settings.py`. Tente `DATE_FORMAT = "%d/%m/%Y"`, ou coloque este formato em `DATE_INPUT_FORMAT = ["%d/%m/%Y"]`.

Comment: @Andreson Incluí o DATE_FORMAT e DATE_INPUT_FORMAT no settings.py, mesmo assim continuo com o erro.

Comment: Imprimi o form, o valor está sendo passado corretamente para view: <tr><th><label for="id_data_nascimento">Data nascimento:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>Informe uma data válida.</li></ul><input type="text" name="data_nascimento" value="22/12/2005" required id="id_data_nascimento" /></td></tr>

Comment: Anderson, consegui.  Você está correto, só faltou um "S" no DATE_INPUT_FORMATS.  Você pode responder para que eu possa marcar a sua resposta?  Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme as [configurações](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/) do Django, há a propriedade [`DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#date-input-formats):

> *A list of formats that will be accepted when inputting data on a date field.*

Isto é, a lista dos formatos que serão aceitos para datas de entrada em campos do tipo data. Por padrão, a propriedade possui o seguinte valor:

```
[
    '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', # '2006-10-25', '10/25/2006', '10/25/06'
    '%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y',            # 'Oct 25 2006', 'Oct 25, 2006'
    '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y',            # '25 Oct 2006', '25 Oct, 2006'
    '%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y',            # 'October 25 2006', 'October 25, 2006'
    '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y',            # '25 October 2006', '25 October, 2006'
]
```

Você pode alterá-lo conforme desejar, mas caso queira apenas um formato válido, basta fazer:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d/%m/%Y']
```

As alterações supracitadas devem ser feitas no arquivo `settings.py` do projeto.